# What are these user biographies that say the user is zero in something?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

In the last few weeks, I saw a handful of biographies that simply said "I am zero in iOS" or some phrase with the same meaning. Here are [two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4601900/jon-snow) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2783370/anbu-karthik). Surprisingly, these particular users do not seem to be "zero" in the subject they are talking about, moreover, they usually have thousands of reputation.

What are these? Should I take them literally? Is this a meme? Am I out of something?

Comment: Its Jon Snow. He knows nothing :|

Comment: @suraj Obvious references aside, this user was just one of the few that I found.

Comment: perhaps a sort of a humble brag? saying they haven't achieved expertise even when they have the knowledge. All we can do is speculate..

Comment: Based on what shows up in Google, it seems to be a rather uncommon expression. It's probably just a case of your brain trying to see a pattern where there isn't one.

Comment: I also found [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8246224/i-am-the-most-stupid-person) who says they're the most stupid person.

Comment: It means that they wish their questions to be given the lowest possible priority.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd never heard of this before, and it has no obvious meaning in the context of the English language.

It's possible it's some kind of meme from popular culture, given that the user is named "Jon Snow", who is [a character in a popular television series, *Game of Thrones*](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/you-know-nothing-jon-snow), as suraj suggested.

However, that's a bit of a stretch, and as you said, you found other users saying the same thing in their profiles with no other references to *Game of Thrones*.

Therefore, the most likely explanation, supported by [what I can find on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i+am+zero+in%22), is it's some kind of fixed phrase in Indian English—or just a common, incorrect usage. For example:

- [I am zero in english but i can tell you...](https://boardofwisdom.com/togo/Quotes/ShowQuote?msgid=308137&msgid=308137#.Wb-2Bp_6xOg)
- [I am zero in mechanical engineering. Is it possible for me to start and complete full GATE syllabus in 6 months?](https://www.quora.com/I-am-zero-in-mechanical-engineering-Is-it-possible-for-me-to-start-and-complete-full-GATE-syllabus-in-6-months)
- [I want to learn Java? But everyone know that its hard to learn I am zero in basic concept](https://www.quora.com/I-want-to-learn-Java-But-everyone-know-that-its-hard-to-learn-I-am-zero-in-basic-concept)
- [I am zero in knowledge, zero in actions and zero in emotions. You have knowledge more than me.](https://books.google.com/books?id=H24zDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT9&lpg=PT9&dq=%22i+am+zero+in%22&source=bl&ots=SWl1TZ2MS0&sig=WGh9HvcJABJlaFhC8gkIe6za8Gg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje2LG32K7WAhXIxlQKHerwCgQQ6AEIUzAN#v=onepage&q=%22i%20am%20zero%20in%22&f=false)
- [Not at all. I am zero in this area. In fact I never had any girlfriend. I actively avoided all girls.](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mx3_CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT70&lpg=PT70&dq=%22i+am+zero+in%22&source=bl&ots=Z82--3bS-M&sig=tEEm9W-Njj-hH1SYSAfGBJrI6hI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje2LG32K7WAhXIxlQKHerwCgQQ6AEIWTAP#v=onepage&q=%22i%20am%20zero%20in%22&f=false)

In other words, it's just a (grammatically incorrect) way of saying that they don't know much about the technology. They probably wrote the profile when they first joined Stack Overflow, and have since learned a lot more than "zero".